# could not find function "randomForest" error while Calling the R script in java. But working fine in R

Tags: java, r, random-forest, rserve

```
RConnection connection = null;

/* Create a connection to Rserve instance running on default port
 * 6311
 */

try{
    /* Create a connection to Rserve instance running
     * on default port 6311
     */
    connection = new RConnection();

    /* Note four slashes (\\\\) in the path */
    connection.eval("source('E:\\\\MyScript.R')");

    REXP sum =connection.parseAndEval("try(eval(predictSAL()),silent=TRUE)");
    System.out.println("The sum is=" + sum.asString());
} catch (RserveException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (REngineException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I was trying to execute this code in java. Calling the R script here is causing one error could not find function `randomForest`. It showed the same error for rhe first time in R console. But then I executed install.packages(`randomForest`) and library(randomFroest) then it started working fine. But still it is not working when called from java. Do I need to make some more change anywhere?

Comment: `library(randomFroest)` should be in the beggining of your R script. Is it?

Comment: `library(randomForest)` is only effective for the running process. Java is starting a new process, so you need to include that before you use the function. Perhaps add `connection.eval("library(randomForest)");` after you assign to `connection`.

Comment: Great r2evans. Thanks it worked like a charm. Any Idea about how to use this Rconnection in android?

Comment: I am building one Android machine learning app where in a java class I need to make a call to a R script. But before that I need to make sure that R is up and running. How do I do that? How to get the Rconnection established in android code?